# Popup should not open when the second time i refresh the home page using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var firstTime = localStorage.getItem("firstTime");

  if (!firstTime) {
    // all your current code

    jQuery('.home #footera').on("click", function(e) {
      jQuery(".pum-overlay").css("display", "block");

      jQuery(".pum-overlay").css("position", "relative");

      jQuery(".pum-container").css("display", "block");
      jQuery("#footera").css("display", "none");
    });

    jQuery(".pum-close").click(function($) {
      jQuery(".home #footera").css("display", "block");
    });

    localStorage.setItem("firstTime", true);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There is a popup on the home page. I don't want the popup to open whenever user refreshes the page or come back to home page from some other inner pages.

How can I make the popup/Newsletter not to open when I second time refreshes the home page.

```
I tried following codes suggested by stackoverflow:
    $(document).ready(function() {  

        var firstTime = localStorage.getItem("firstTime");

        if(! firstTime){
           // all your current code

             jQuery('.home #footera').on("click", function(e){
jQuery(".pum-overlay").css("display","block");

jQuery(".pum-overlay").css("position","relative");

jQuery(".pum-container").css("display","block");
jQuery("#footera").css("display","none"); 
  });

jQuery(".pum-close").click(function($){
     jQuery(".home #footera").css("display","block"); 
    });

           localStorage.setItem("firstTime", true);
        }

    });
```

Comment: use `cookie` for preventing popup second time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to check the browser refresh count. You can set the condition after that if it is greater than 1 than popup not open. I see that you give the css for same element 2 times, its only add the lines of code and load also. You can give the multiple css on same selector.

For checking the count of refreshi will add the fiddle here, you can check the value and manage according it for your logic.

https://jsfiddle.net/bk8bfo4g/1/

For add multiple css:

```
jQuery(".pum-overlay").css({'position':'relative','display' : 'block'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution if you want to prevent popup from reopening after first visit is use `cookie`.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  
    var cookieValue = $.cookie("test"); //any name you want to give
    if(empty(cookieValue)){
        $.cookie("test", 1, { expires : 10 }); //test is the name of cookie and expires : 10 is for 10 days. You can set that according to your requirement 
        //your popup code
    }
 }
```